# What am I doing wrong with Interceptor and Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

### I have been sitting on this problem more than 1 day, and I cannot understand what the problem is. I want to get the username from the server.The server waits for a token from me and returns the user data

**API**

```
@GET("/users/profile/")
    Call<UserProfile> getProfile();
```

**RETROFIT AND OKHTTPCLIENT**

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        SharedPreferences preferences = App.Companion.getInstance().getSharedPreferences("userInfo", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .addInterceptor(new AccessTokenInterceptor(preferences))
                .build();

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

**OWN CLASS FOR INTERCEPTOR**

```
class AccessTokenInterceptor constructor(
        private val preferences: SharedPreferences) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        val token: String? = preferences.getString("access_token", null)
        proceed(
                request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization",token.toString())
                        .build()
        )
    }
}
```

**The class where I am trying to catch the response. Here is my second question. Is this class even needed?**

```
class ProfileRepository(application: Application)  {
    val liveDataProfile = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var application: Application? = application

    fun getProfileInfo(): LiveData<String> {

        val call: Call<UserProfile>? = NetworkService.getInstance()
                .jsonApi
                .getProfile()
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<UserProfile>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserProfile>, response: Response<UserProfile>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()?.let {
                        liveDataProfile.value = it.username
                        Log.i("LogProfile","Мы получили имя пользователя с сервака = " +  it.username)
                    }
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserProfile>, t: Throwable) {}
        })

        return liveDataProfile
    }
    
}
```

**RESPONSE FROM SERVER**

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET https://minesrv.ey.r.appspot.com/users/profile/
    --> END GET
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 400 https://minesrv.ey.r.appspot.com/users/profile/
```

Comment: response from server is 400 (bad request), maybe your parameter are missing or empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `/` before the request . When you add `/` the users will be removed from final url, making the url invalid . From above info you given this should be the problem .

```
@GET("users/profile/")
Call<UserProfile> getProfile();
```

Comment: @GET("/users/profile/") is not the problem. I tested @GET("/api/users/profile/")  and so on